# Problem Creating Cascading Drop-down Lists in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, edit-form, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint list with called Service Areas and Directors with 2 Columns:
DirectorList & Team

The DirectorList column specifies the category which each Team sits within. I am trying to create a PowerApps customization for the New and Edit forms to allow me to select the Director and in my first drop-down list and then select Team from a filtered list of those reporting to that Director from the second.

To this end I have created 2 Text Columns called ServiceDirector and ServiceAreaTeam. These are in a list view and the list form has been customized with PowerApps.

The ServiceDirector datacard has had the text control replaced with a dropdown list called ServiceDropdown3.
The 'Update' field contains the following: ServiceDropdown3.Selected.Result

The Items field of ServiceDropdown3 contains the following: Sort(Distinct('Service Area and Directors'.DirectorList, DirectorList), Result, Ascending)

The ServiceAreaTeam datacard has had the text control replaced with a dropdown list called ServiceDropdown4.
The 'Update' field contains the following: ServiceDropdown4.Selected.Team

The Items field of ServiceDropdown4 contains the following: Filter('Service Area and Directors',Team=ServiceDropdown3.Selected.Result)

When published the App produces no errors and the first drop down functions as expected, producing a selectable list of Directors with no duplications. The second dropdown remains blank.

Why does the second list not produce a filtered list of teams reporting to that director, as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The formula used on `DataCard.Update` validates and pushes back into the data source only when `SubmitForm` runs, but not when the form is being filled. So I don't think this is the property you should use.

I tried to duplicate your form structure, but I got a bunch of errors on formulas. Would you provide screenshots of the form and your list for clarification?

Also, I think you will need a second list for cascading to work. Here is sample reference in case you need it: [Cascading Dropdowns in PowerApps SharePoint Lookups.](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/03/cascading-dropdowns-in-powerapps-sharepoint-lookups/)